# Apply a function for each array

Tags: php

I'm trying to apply a function for each array but it doesnt work, here's my code:

```
$array['a'] = "aaa";
$array['b'] = "bbb";

function myFunction ($array) {
   ## some code
   };

foreach ($array as $value) {
   echo myFunction($array[$value]);
   };
```

Thx for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
$array['a'] = "aaa";
$array['b'] = "bbb";

function myFunction ($array) {
   ## some code
   };

foreach ($array as $key => $value){
   echo myFunction( $value );
};
```

Answer (score 4):

karthikr is correct. you can also use a shorthand function instead of your foreach loop:

```
array_walk($array, 'myFunction');
```

see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php

Answer (score 2):

As for your title, if you need to apply a callback function to every (more than 1) array, let's use [array_map()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
$func = function($value) {  
  return $value * 2;  
};

print_r(array_map($func, range(1, 5)));
```